# Dimmer with 2x MOSFET + isolation

Tags: mosfet, dimmer, dimming

I'm working on a test schematics for LED dimmer with MOSFETs rather than TRIACs. Some part of the schematics (MOSFET part) is taken from various websites, but combination below was never seen as a one solution.

### Schematics (from LTspice)

[image]

### How it works

- 2 MOSFETs to control any phase when MOSFETs are open or closed
- D1, R5, D3, C1 provide simple 12V power supply - D3 is 12V Zener
- PC817 optocopler, controller by MCU, opens gate w/ 12V compared to source voltage.

This is the current through the R1 load that simulated "LED". It is not a perfect load since it is only resistive. Pulse generator is set to `0.5 ms` on time, every `1 ms`. We see nice duty cycle of 50% and peak current of `~320 mA`

[image]

Should I be considering adding some more components - more as a protection, for instance?

Comment: Why not use a simple bidirectional solid-state relay?

Comment: You question is more that fair - I'm trying to move from triacs,due to minimum holding current - will SSR help here? Isn't triac inside typically?

Comment: There are triac-type SSRs, and there are MOSFET-type SSRs. Just get a MOSFET one.

Comment: Thanks - I think, looking at Google quickly, what I'm trying to design is exactly that. Will search and buy one.